# Not Root User tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Anyone have any opinions on this tag? good or bad? seems a little odd to me, and seems like it might be starting to get abused by a couple of people. Here's a link to the [not-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-root-user) tag. (note: there are like 6 questions edited pending approval to add it)

Comment: Note that you can also do [tag:not-root-user], and it automatically links to the relevant tag.

Comment: @tshepang good tip ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think `non-root` could have been a better name for this tag. That said, the tag is helpful, in that it shows an important aspect of the problem. It also helps categorize questions, for example, "Installing Chrome" is one, but "Installing Chrome without root access" is another.

I also noticed that a bunch of questions have just been retagged with `not-root-user`, some incorrectly. [Prevent non-root user from formatting a partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6689/250) is an example of a question that should not have been tagged with `not-root-user`, because the problem doesn't involve the user not being able or not wanting to become root. [Non-Root Package Managers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535/250), on the contrary, should have the tag.

Comment: I agree on all points except that I prefer `not-root-user` as the tag names. I've rolled back the tag addition to [Non-Root Package Managers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5535/250).

Comment: @gilles @phunehehe `no-root-access` seems like it might be good, even `without-root`. I dunno, I don't see myself googling "not-root-user" but I might google the other 2 I mentioned.

Comment: I think I like `without-root`, and perhaps convey's things better. what do you guys think?

Comment: @Gilles you meant you rolled back [Prevent non-root user from formatting a partition](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6689/250) right?

Comment: @xenoterracide I think `without-root` is as good as `non-root`

Comment: @phunehehe but I think that "without root" is the more natural way to convey it in language.

Answer (score 2):

One way to determine if a tag is actually useful is to imagine if anyone would subscribe to it (RSS/email). Why would anyone subscribe to this tag is a bit beyond me. Most of the questions here would be on-topic for such a tag anyways (root access is a small part of system usage), so in that case I agree with phunehehe that the tag could have a better name (maybe [nonroot-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonroot-installation)). But even then, is the tag that interesting? Why not just use [installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation).

Let's talk about me. I've used Debian more than any other OS, so I'm more likely to answer a [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) question than a [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum) one. Why would one be more interested in answering [nonroot-install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonroot-install) questions than other [install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/install) questions? Is it really likely that someone would be good in one and not the other, as opposed to the case for [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) and [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum)?

Comment: That's one of the two main reasons for tags. The other is directing searches, and this tag is helpful for that (it conveys some hard-to-search information).

Comment: @gilles I think it is more fair to say that another good use for tags is *grouping similar questions* even if no (sane) user would actually *subscribe* to said tag. This is rather important.

Comment: @JeffAtwood what is the tag for questions most likely to cause insanity in lab rats, I want to subscribe my ex to it.